# Help needed with farbtastic color picker. Simple example html included

Tags: color-picker, color-codes

I've included a very simple html example that almost works.  It is a very plain implementation of this great color picker.  But it doesn't quite work as advertised.   I only get a single blue box and I can pick blue shades.  But not the gradient or the outer ring.
Wait!  I just realized that the outer ring is there, and I can change the colors with it.  But its invisible!  Weird....

Can anybody show me how to get the whole thing to work?

http://bizzocall.com/farbPicker.html

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just a word of advice. The page on your other question, which is essentially a dupe of this one, is causing a log of spam flags to be raised. Next time why not put your demo code somewhere less "in your face".

Comment: Are you talking about spam flags within StackOverflow?  I'm not quite sure what you're talking about, or how I should do it next time.  I thought it was better to provide a link than to put code in the email itself....no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the images for it are not pointing to the correct uri. http://bizzocall.com/css/marker.png returns a 404; point your images to the correct file and you should be straight

Comment: Aha!  Of course!  I just didn't thing to look there.  Thanks for helping out on this little problem.  Now it works great!

Comment: I don't know how to accept your answer. I did say "yes" to the "useful to you" question...What else?

Comment: Can you take a look at my other question?  You seem to know what you're doing....(fooled me, anyway:<)

Comment: The question is "More help needed with fartastic color picker"

Comment: sorry man, i missed that part. its kind of hard to tell what you are asking specifically, but what you want is the farbtastic color plugin. i use it. you can see it/copy it from here entirely. http://dev.bowdenweb.com/tools/in-browser/farbtastic/demo1.html

Answer (score -1):

I have the farbtastic color picker working really well now.  Just for those of you who want an example to take apart and look at, here's a link.  The sytax of how the farbtastic function is called to send the color to numerous items on the page is the tricky part.  But, its working here.  Just look at the source...

http://bizzocall.com/cp-BizzoActiveButton.php