# More help needed with farbtastic color picker

Tags: colors, picker

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Help needed with farbtastic color picker. Simple example html included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7560467/help-needed-with-farbtastic-color-picker-simple-example-html-included)

I need a bit more help with the farbtastic color picker.  I've got it working, and I can get it to change ONE ITEM on my page.  But I need to get it to change the background color on a number of items, and can't figure out how to do it.  Here is an example, where I've tried to do it with the jQuery change() event. Can anybody show me what I'm doing wrong?

http://bizzocall.com/farbtastic/demo1.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have the farbtastic color picker working really well now. Just for those of you who want an example to take apart and look at, here's a link. The sytax of how the farbtastic function is called to send the color to numerous items on the page is the tricky part. But, its working here. Just look at the source...

http://bizzocall.com/cp-BizzoActiveButton.php

This duplicates my answer to the other question. I put it here just in case someone stumbles upon this question instead of the other one.

Comment: your link 404s.  Why not just post the code here?